# Better constant definition approach

Tags: c++, c++14

While exploring SQLite source code for learning purposes I found this in many places within the source code;

```
#define SQLITE_LOCK_NONE          0
#define SQLITE_LOCK_SHARED        1
#define SQLITE_LOCK_RESERVED      2
#define SQLITE_LOCK_PENDING       3
#define SQLITE_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE     4

#define SQLITE_IOCAP_ATOMIC                 0x00000001
#define SQLITE_IOCAP_ATOMIC512              0x00000002
#define SQLITE_IOCAP_ATOMIC1K               0x00000004
#define SQLITE_IOCAP_ATOMIC2K               0x00000008
#define SQLITE_IOCAP_ATOMIC4K               0x00000010
```

Is this standard in modern C++ (C++11, 14, 17) or are there different ways to do this in modern C++?

Comment: _"or are there different ways to do this in modern C++?"_ One would use enums rather than `#define`.

Comment: for constants anything is better than `#define`. whats wrong with `const int SQLITE_LOCK_NONE = 0;`? But actually it looks like you want an enum

Comment: Isn't SQLite written in C? How can it be compared with modern C++?

Comment: @tobi303 _"whats wrong with `const int`"_ It occupies memory in the text segment.

Comment: @user0042 well still better than occupiying names that are not restricted to any namespace or anything

Comment: @taskinoor, I'm not comparing the two languages. I'm learning the SQLite library, along the course of learning how to use it I find areas which I think there could be a better way to do in C++. Just to strengthen my knowledge on C++.

Comment: @user 0042 It should be optimized away by the compiler if it is only ever used in constant expressions. In modern C++ you can declare it `constexpr`.

Comment: @patatahooligan Yes, I was already about mentioning `constexpr` to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there never was a reason to use `#define` for constants in C++. You can always write

```
const int my_constant = 42;
```

For your case you probably want an enum

```
enum SQLITE_LOCK {SQLITE_LOCK_NONE, SQLITE_LOCK_SHARED, SQLITE_LOCK_RESERVED, 
      SQLITE_LOCK_PENDING, SQLITE_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE };
```

And that is something that really improved a lot in c++11, as you can now use scoped enums as

```
enum class SQLITE_LOCK { .... };
```

PS: modern C++ also has `constexpr` for compile time constants, but I am not familiar enough to say anything about it.